# Niether 'MPI_Barrier' nor 'BLACS_Barrier' doesn't stop a processors executing its commands

Tags: fortran, mpi, scalapack, blacs

I'm working on ScaLAPACK and trying to get used to BLACS routines which is essential using ScaLAPACK.

I've had some elementary course on MPI, so have some rough idea of MPI_COMM_WORLD stuff, but has no deep understanding on how it works internally and so on.

Anyway, I'm trying following code to say hello using BLACS routine.

```
   program hello_from_BLACS
     use MPI
     implicit none

     integer  :: info, nproc, nprow, npcol, &
                 myid, myrow, mycol, &
                 ctxt, ctxt_sys, ctxt_all

     call BLACS_PINFO(myid, nproc)

     ! get the internal default context
     call BLACS_GET(0, 0, ctxt_sys)

     ! set up a process grid for the process set
     ctxt_all = ctxt_sys
     call BLACS_GRIDINIT(ctxt_all, 'c', nproc, 1)
     call BLACS_BARRIER(ctxt_all, 'A')

     ! set up a process grid of size 3*2
     ctxt = ctxt_sys
     call BLACS_GRIDINIT(ctxt, 'c', 3, 2)

     if (myid .eq. 0) then
       write(6,*) '                          myid       myrow       mycol       nprow       npcol'
     endif

(**) call BLACS_BARRIER(ctxt_sys, 'A')

     ! all processes not belonging to 'ctxt' jump to the end of the program
     if (ctxt .lt. 0) goto 1000

     ! get the process coordinates in the grid
     call BLACS_GRIDINFO(ctxt, nprow, npcol, myrow, mycol)
     write(6,*) 'hello from process', myid, myrow, mycol, nprow, npcol

1000 continue

     ! return all BLACS contexts
     call BLACS_EXIT(0)
     stop
   end program
```

and the output with 'mpirun -np 10 ./exe' is like,

```
 hello from process           0           0           0           3           2
 hello from process           4           1           1           3           2
 hello from process           1           1           0           3           2
                           myid       myrow       mycol       nprow       npcol
 hello from process           5           2           1           3           2
 hello from process           2           2           0           3           2
 hello from process           3           0           1           3           2
```

Everything seems to work fine except that 'BLACS_BARRIER' line, which I marked (**) in the code's leftside.

I've put that line to make the output like below whose title line always printed at the top of the it.

```
                           myid       myrow       mycol       nprow       npcol
 hello from process           0           0           0           3           2
 hello from process           4           1           1           3           2
 hello from process           1           1           0           3           2
 hello from process           5           2           1           3           2
 hello from process           2           2           0           3           2
 hello from process           3           0           1           3           2
```

So the question goes,

1. I've tried BLACS_BARRIER to 'ctxt_sys', 'ctxt_all', and 'ctxt' but all of them does not make output in which the title line is firstly printed. I've also tried MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD,info), but it didn't work either. Am I using the barriers in the wrong way?
2. In addition, I got SIGSEGV when I used BLACS_BARRIER to 'ctxt' and used more than 6 processes when executing mpirun. Why SIGSEGV takes place in this case?

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: Welcome. I suggest to take the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: The barriers are not enough to order the output as you want. They synchronise the processes at that point, but have nothing to say about synchronising relative to the various bits of the operating system which deal with I/O. The only practical ways to guarantee ordering of I/O are 1) MPI I/O     2) Have on process handle all the I/O

Comment: You are getting a segfault because processes are calling blacs_barrier with an invalid context. You create a grid with 6 procs. Only 6 procs are part of the context. Any other procs are not part of the context. And thus calling blacs_barrier causes a seg fault

Comment: your output has `hello from process 0` printed **before** `myid`. unless this is a copy/paste error, you have some serious memory corruption in your program.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet From Ian's answer, I was getting like 'Hmm, there's something complex going on between I/O process and actual code's memory thing', thus expecting it's about just I/O process, rather than expecting any memory problem in my posted code.  Can you elaborate a little more for me if it's expected to be from some memory corruption problem?

Comment: Gilles' point is that while I/O from different processes is difficult to order, I/O from the a single given process should always be in the order you perform it. In your code the process with rank 0 prints 'myid ...' and then some integers. In your example out put which is "wrong" the I/O for rank 0 is the other way round. this should not happen.

Comment: On spot. If the output you posted legit? Or is this a copy/paste error?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Oh, I got it. Indeed the output is a legit one, but the code I posted was modified when I was writing the question. It was the 'myid == 2' process that printed the posted output, which I changed to 0th process writing the question. I was just doing some experiment changing I/O printing processor to see how the orders of I/O changes. Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: It is always a good idea to have the output match the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 2 questions (in future it is best to give then separate posts)

1) MPI_Barrier, BLACS_Barrier and any barrier in any parallel programming methodology I have come across only synchronises the actual set of processes that calls it. However I/O is not dealt with just by the calling process, but at least one and quite possibly more within the OS which actually the process the I/O request. These are NOT synchronised by your barrier. Thus ordering of I/O is not ensured by a simple barrier. The only standard conforming ways that I can think of to ensure ordering of I/O are

- Have 1 process do all the I/O or
- Better is to use MPI I/O either directly, or indirectly, via e.g. NetCDF or HDF5

2) Your second call to BLACS_GRIDINIT

```
 call BLACS_GRIDINIT(ctxt, 'c', 3, 2)
```

creates a context for 3 by 2 process grid, so holding 6 process. If you call it with more than 6 processes, only 6 will be returned with a valid context, for the others `ctxt` should be treated as an uninitialised value. So for instance if you call it with 8 processes, 6 will return with a valid `ctxt`, 2 will return with `ctxt` having no valid value. If these 2 now try to use `ctxt` anything is possible, and in your case you are getting a seg fault. You do seem to see that this is an issue as later you have

```
 ! all processes not belonging to 'ctxt' jump to the end of the program
 if (ctxt .lt. 0) goto 1000
```

but I see nothing in the description of BLACS_GRIDINIT that ensures ctxt will be less than zero for non-participating processes - at https://www.netlib.org/blacs/BLACS/QRef.html#BLACS_GRIDINIT it says

> This routine creates a simple NPROW x NPCOL process grid. This process
>   grid will use the first NPROW x NPCOL processes, and assign them to
>   the grid in a row- or column-major natural ordering. If these
>   process-to-grid mappings are unacceptable, BLACS_GRIDINIT's more
>   complex sister routine BLACS_GRIDMAP must be called instead.

There is no mention of what `ctxt` will be if the process is not part of the resulting grid - this is the kind of problem I find regularly with the BLACS documentation. Also please don't use `goto`, for your own sake. You WILL regret it later. Use `If ... End If`. I can't remember when I last used `goto` in Fortran, it may well be over 10 years ago.

Finally good luck in using BLACS! In my experience the documentation is often incomplete, and I would suggest only using those calls that are absolutely necessary to use ScaLAPACK and using MPI, which is much, much better defined, for the rest. It would be so much nicer if ScaLAPACK just worked with MPI nowadays.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a reply, and it helped me getting some hack of BLACS, and the concept of 'context'. I don't use 'goto' statement usually, was just following an example from a website which I found in searching examples for the ScaLAPACK's PDGEMR2D subroutine to distribute my matrix over MPI processes(https://info.gwdg.de/wiki/doku.php?id=wiki:hpc:scalapack). Thank you again for your answer, have a nice day :)