# Coarray sync all failing

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, fortran-coarrays

I'm learning to use Fortran's coarrays but I'm having a very strange behaviour that I don't understand. I run the following very simple loop

```
do i = 1, 100
    print*, this_image(), i
    sync all
    if (this_image() .eq. 1) print*
    sync all
end do
```

I expect the output to have each image print its index and then the value of the iterator, then wait for the first image to print a blank line, then continue, e.g.

```
1 1
2 1
4 1 
3 1

2 2
3 2 
4 2 
1 2

...
```

etcetera. But instead I got output

```
       1           1
       2           1
       4           1

       3           1
       3           2
       1           2

       1           3

       1           4
       2           2
       2           3
       2           4
       3           3
       3           4
       3           5
       4           2
       4           3
       4           4
       4           5
       4           6

       1           5

       ...
```

So it appears to me that the treads are not following the `sync all` commands. I do observe quite different behaviour if I remove the `sync all` however.

Am I misunderstanding what `sync all` does? I thought it was a global barrier that prevented any thread from continuing until all threads had completed their current tasks. Thus each thread should finish the first print, then the first thread must finish printing the new line, before any thread can move on to the second loop. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't do Co-array Fortran, but I would expect it to be like MPI and OpenMP here, and have no guarantee that the output is ordered when you write to the same unit number as you observe  -you will have to do something cleverer than this. The ultimate reason is that not only do you have to sync/order the program (which I expect will be) you *also* have to correctly order *every* *single* layer of the OS below this that actually does the I/O, and it is this that is *not* guaranteed. There must be something here that explains this, but I can't find one at the moment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678599/niether-mpi-barrier-nor-blacs-barrier-doesnt-stop-a-processors-executing-it Goes through it for the MPI case in a little more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sync all` is not sufficient to ensure the ordering that you require. Quoting Metcalf, Reid, Cohen and Bader in "Modern Fortran Explained Incorporating Fortran 2023", section 17.20

> The default unit for output ( `*` in a `write` statement or `output_unit` in
> the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env` ) and ... are preconnected on
> each image. The files to which these are connected are regarded as
> separate, but it is expected that a processor will merge their records
> into a single stream or a stream for output_unit and ... .
> Synchronization and flush statements might be sufficient to control
> the ordering of the records, but this is not guaranteed.

This is essentially the same as for MPI - there the only ways to ensure ordered records are via MPI-IO or by a single process performing all the I/O.

Comment: Thanks! I really need a copy of that book. But other than IO, `sync all` should be sufficient for function calls and operations shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can sync your routines, but that doesn't necessarily sync anything external you call